# php - PHPUnit with PCOV code coverage show 0% coverage on window

Tags: phpunit, php-code-coverage, pcov

I use phpUnit with PCOV on code coverage on window.  But somehow, I get 0.0% code coverage. I am sure the function is called. Why is this happening?

Versions:

- PHP: `8.1.12`
- PHPUnit: `9.5.0`
- PCOV: `1.0.11`

## The running log is as follows

```
PS C:\xampp\php> vendor\bin\phpunit
PHPUnit 9.5.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 8.1.12
Configuration: C:\xampp\php\phpunit.xml

R                                        1 / 1 (100%)Called1
Time: 00:00.215, Memory: 10.00 MB
There was 1 risky test:

1) AAATest::testaccess
This test printed output: Called1
OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Risky: 1.
PS C:\xampp\php\
```

## Following is my simplified code `AAA.php`

```php
class AAA
{
    public $flag;
    public function __construct($flag)
    {
        $this->flag = $flag;
    }

    public function access()
    {
        $this->flag = 1;
    }
}
```

## Following is my testing AAATest.php

```php
<?php

require '/xampp/php/vendor/autoload.php';
require '/xampp/htdocs/Performance/scripts-php/AAA.php';

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\CodeCoverage;
use SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\Driver\Driver;
use SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\Filter;
use SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\Report\Html\Facade as HtmlReport;

$filter = new Filter;
$filter->includeFile('/xampp/htdocs/Performance/scripts-php/AAA.php');
$driver = Driver::forLineCoverage($filter);
$coverage = new CodeCoverage($driver, $filter);

$flag = 0;

class AAATest extends TestCase
{
    protected $AAA;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        global $flag;
        global $coverage;
        $this->AAA = new AAA($flag);
        print("Called");
    }

    /**
     * @covers AAA::access
    */
    public function testaccess()
    {
        global $flag;
        global $coverage;

        $coverage->start('testaccess');

        $this->AAA->access();

        print($this->AAA->flag);

        $this->assertEquals(1, $this->AAA->flag);

        $coverage->stop();

        (new HtmlReport)->process($coverage, 'code-coverage-report\report');
    }
}
```

## Following is the `php.ini`

```
........
extension=php_gd
extension=php_pcov
extension=gettext
.......
```

## Following is the `phpunit.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/9.5/phpunit.xsd"
        bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
        cacheResultFile=".phpunit.cache/test-results"
        executionOrder="depends,defects"
        forceCoversAnnotation="true"
        beStrictAboutCoversAnnotation="true"
        beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests="true"
        beStrictAboutTodoAnnotatedTests="true"
        convertDeprecationsToExceptions="true"
        failOnRisky="true"
        failOnWarning="true"
        verbose="true">

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="default">
            <file>/xampp/htdocs/Performance/scripts-php/AAA.php</file>
            <directory>/xampp/htdocs/Performance/scripts-php/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>


    <coverage cacheDirectory=".phpunit.cache/code-coverage"
            processUncoveredFiles="true"
    >
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">/xampp/htdocs/Performance/scripts-php</directory>
        </include>
        <exclude>
            <directory>./vendor</directory>
            <directory>./tests</directory>
        </exclude>
    </coverage>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    </php>

</phpunit>
```

## Following is the `composer.json`

```json
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "9.5",
        "phpunit/php-code-coverage": "^9.2",
        "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": "^9.0",
        "pcov/clobber": "^2.0"
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.0",
        "php-webdriver/webdriver": "1.13.1",
        "symfony/symfony": "5.2"
    }
}
```

Here is the result. I am expecting 100% code coverage

```
C:\xampp\php\code-coverage-report\report\AAA.php.html
    
                       Code Coverage          
       Lines                        Functions and Methods               Classes and Traits
Total 
  0.00% covered(danger)    0.00% 0/2 0.00% covered(danger)    0.00% 0/2 CRAP0.00% covered (danger)  0.00%  0/1
AAA 
  0.00% covered (danger)   0.00% 0/2 0.00% covered(danger)    0.00% 0/26 0.00% covered (danger)
0.00% 0/1
 __construct    
  0.00% covered(danger)    0.00% 0/1 0.00% covered(danger)    0.00% 0/1 2   
access  
  0.00% covered (danger)   0.00% 0/1 0.00% covered(danger)    0.00% 0/1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the source directory (and the excludes) to the [`pcov` configuration](https://github.com/krakjoe/pcov#configuration) in your `php.ini` as well:

```ini
pcov.directory = "/xampp/htdocs/Performance/scripts-php"
pcov.exclude   = "#/(vendor|tests)/#"
```

See this [related issue](https://github.com/krakjoe/pcov/issues/49).